# How to Show the value in textbox based on selection of item from dropdown list in mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I update my textboxes to display the `Email1` and `Mobile1` properties of my `Contact` model based on the selected value in a dropdownlist

View

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName , new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @style = "width:250px;" })

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email1, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactID, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email1)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo1, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactID, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo1)
```

Script

```
$('#CustomerContactID').change(function () {
    $('#ContactID').empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/VisitorsForm/GetEmailByCustomerContactId",
        datatype: "Json",
        data: { CustomerContactID: $('#CustomerContactID').val() },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Email1').val(data.Email1);
            $('#MobileNo1').val(data.Mobile1);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult GetEmailByCustomerContactId(string CustomerContactId)
{
    Guid Id = Guid.Parse(CustomerContactId);
    var contacts = from a in db.Contacts where a.ContactID == Id select a;
    return Json(contacts);
}
```

Comment: What is not working? What errors are your getting? `var contacts = from a in db.Contacts where a.ContactID == Id select a; return Json(contacts);` returns a collection and a collection does not have a property named `Email1` or `Mobile1`. Suggest you delete 90% of your code which is not relevant to your question and focus on the issue and then you will get an answer.

Comment: Actually the email and MobileNo is in contact Table

Comment: i didnt get any errors

Comment: Did you not understand my last comment (and I know _the Email and MobileNo is in contact table_ - that's irrelevant)

Comment: did the answer help @Vani

Comment: @Vani, Before you go any further, you need to go to the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and read all the topics, especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I spent a considerable amount of time editing to question to meet the standards of this site (and to be able to give you an answer) and you just undid it all. I have now rolled them back to my original changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your query in the `GetEmailByCustomerContactId()` returns `IEnumerable<Contact>`, a collection, not a single object, so `data` in the ajax success call back is an array and `$('#Email1').val(data.Email1);` fails because an array does not have a property named `Email1` (but each item in the collection does)

Since you only want to return one `Contact`, change your query to

```
var contact = (from a in db.Contacts where a.ContactID == Id select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

and since you only want 2 properties of `Contact`, then return an anonymous object containing only those properties (there is no point degrading performance by sending data across the wire which you never use

```
var data = new { Email1 = contact.Email1, Mobile1 = contact.Mobile1 };
```

and finally specify the `JsonRequestBehavior` option since your making a GET call

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;);
```

Next, your not generating any inputs with `id="Email1"` and `id="Mobile1"`. Both textboxes you have create bind to `ContactID`, so I assume these should be

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email1, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mobile1, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

assuming that `Email1` and `Mobile1` are also properties of the model in the view.

Your textboxes will now be updated in the `success` callback

Side notes:

1. Always use `url: '@Url.Action(....)',` to ensure the correct url is
   generated
2. Use `data: { CustomerContactID: $(this).val() },`
3. Change your method parameter to `public JsonResult
   GetEmailByCustomerContactId(Guid CustomerContactId)` and delete the
   `Guid.Parse` (the `DefaultModelBinder` will do the conversion)
4. Remove `new { type = "text" }` from your `Html.TextBoxFor()` methods
   (the helper already adds that)